# Non-Blocking Delays vs Blocking Delays

Tags: c, delay, stm32

I am currently making some additions to some code for a STM32F3 MCU that I did not write. Part of what the product will do is blink LEDs at 1Hz while testing until the MCU determines if the test is pass or fail.

The previous writer of this code implemented two delays; one that is a for loop based off the clock rate, the other off a timer interrupt. The first delay gets called like this

```
MsDelay(1000); //Provides approx a one second delay via a for loop
```

The other like this

```
Wait(x,y); //x indicates the timer channel, y is delay in milliseconds
```

The "wait(x,y)" function goes through a clock tick check and some incrementing to implement this delay.

The problem I'm having is in the LED blinking I talked about earlier. To test this function, in the ISR for the test, I call

```
Set_Led(1,1); //Turns LED1 ON
Wait(1,1000); //Wait one second 
Set_Led(2,1); //Turns LED2 ON
```

However, there is not a one second delay between the LEDs turning on. However, if I call,

```
Set_Led(1,1); //Turns LED1 ON
MsDelay(1000); //Wait one second 
Set_Led(2,1); //Turns LED2 ON
```

There is a one second delay. I am not very familiar with the differences of blocking vs non-blocking delays other than blocking takes all processing power away from other peripherals. Should there not be a pause between the LEDs turning when using the non-blocking delay? Thank You.

Comment: You don't want to do any type of `wait`ing while you're in an `ISR`

Comment: All depends on what your delay functions are actually doing. Looks like your `Wait` function isn't doing what you think it is doing...

Comment: Both are blocking

Comment: To generate a delay like this, both functions must be blocking. To generate a non blocking blink led you have to define a timer interrupt every second and toggle the LED in the timer interrupt routine.

Comment: You can also set a status flag in the interrupt and poll the status flag in your main application.